# Autocomplete method structure in Vim

Tags: ruby, vim

Does anyone know if there's a way to autocomplete a method in Vim? For an example in Ruby, if I type:

```
def my_method
```

and hit Enter, it would fill in the `end` and move the cursor to where the x is:

```
def my_method
  x
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[vim-endwise](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) does this (I've been happy enough with it to not uninstall it, so I guess that's an endorsement even).

Comment: That doesn't say anything - who in their right mind would uninstall a Tim Pope's plugin?