# vim autocomplete on certain keywords

Tags: vim, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Autocomplete method structure in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498492/autocomplete-method-structure-in-vim)

So I have smart autocomplete features on my vim, where it autocompletes '{' with '}' on a new line and redirects control to next line just like eclipse. So typing '{' and pressing enter gives me

```
{
  |
}
```

Where '|' shows my cursor position. I want something eclipse style for ruby where as soon as write 'def' it should result in

```
def |
end
```

The problem is this should only take effect when 'def' is on the beginning of the line, and not otherwise.

Comment: do you know [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2386)?

Comment: @gokcehan you should put a description of that plugin and the link to it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there seems to be a plugin named [endwise](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2386). I have never tried but it sound like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would also recommend a plugin. General plugins that expand text (but usually the expansion happens only you press and additional key like `tab` are snipmate or my favorite [ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715).

With these plugins with the proper snippets you would type `def<tab>` and it would expand to what you like. I know that ultisnips gives you the option of expanding only in the beginning of line, not sure about snipmate.

Just for fun if you don't want to use a plugin you can define the following in your .vimrc and it will acomplish what you want:

```
imap <expr> def (getpos(".")[2] == 1) ? "def\<CR>end\<UP> ":"def"
```